# jQuery clone list items matching two data attributes

Tags: jquery, clone, matching, custom-data-attribute

I have a list containing list items with a data attribute like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-c="usa">...</li>
    <li data-c="russia">...</li>
    <li data-c="usa">...</li>
</ul>
```

Then I clone/append with jQuery the items that belong to a specific data attribute:

```
var c = $(".select option:selected" ).text();
$("li[data-c='" + c + "']").clone().appendTo(".someClass" );
```

It works just fine.

Now I would like to add a second data attribute like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-c="usa"    data-t="1940">...</li>
    <li data-c="russia" data-t="1940">...</li>
    <li data-c="usa"    data-t="2014">...</li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery would start like this:

```
var c=$( ".select1 option:selected" ).text();
var t=$( ".select2 option:selected" ).text();
....
```

How could I edit the clone/append part in order to get items that are matching both c and t?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BtG68/3/)):

```
var c = 'usa', t = '1940';
$("li[data-c='" + c + "'][data-t='" + t + "']").clone().appendTo(".someClass" );
```

Elements that matches both `data` attribute will be cloned and appended.